# iwlwifi: expected hw-decrypted unicast frame for station

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, wifi, iwd

I have Arch linux installed on my laptop. I experience unstable wifi connection and often disconnects from wifi.

In journal I have this log thousands times:

```
oct 03 12:23:00 arch-thinkpad kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: expected hw-decrypted unicast frame for station
```

How can I fix this ?
Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to add this:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 swcrypto=1
```

to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`